# What are the guidelines and regulations for building a helipad for multiple aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter, airport, easa-regulations, helipad

Are there any guidelines and regulations governing the ownership and construction of a multiple aircraft type helipad in

a) the USA
b) Europe?

Comment: Do you mean Helipads that are often seen on rooftops in cities? The ones I've noticed are only big enough for one craft at a time.  Or do you mean at a more remote location, like part of a pier, or an airport, where there is room for more than 1?

Comment: We already have multiple questions about building an airport in the US, e.g. [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39535/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1383/62), and the basic answer is always the same: construction ultimately depends on local (state/county) zoning regulations. What exactly do you need to know that isn't already answered in those questions?

Comment: @CrossRoads I'm saying constructed both on  rooftops and those in remote locations, however by different aircraft trypes, I mean some have more weight than others and others have wheels instead of blades or rails as landing gear

Comment: @Pondlife I'd like to know the specific guidelines with regards to construction and approval of heliports like it has to be 5.this X 5.this diameter or wide, it has to have x to x to x concrete mixture advisory on non landing paved area at least 10.this x 10.this area.  It must have a 20.this x 20.this clear surrounding otherwise we won approve! If you let trees grow and continue to land you will flout the safety rules and go to jail, minimum x years to life...  measure ments in Scientific units like metres, centimeters and millimetres will be great appreaciated. Also Kgs and grams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAA publishes an [Advisory Circular](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/150_5390-2) on heliport design.  It applies to heliports serving helicopters with a single rotor.  I don't believe that there are any regulations regarding "ownership".  They just have to be operated in compliance with appropriate FAA, state and local regulations (but these can get complicated)